# Link to button from aspx page in a regular html page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms, input

I have an aspx page that contains a "Purchase" button. This page is not user friendly, so I am designing my own page in html, and want to put the Purchase button from the aspx page in the new page, so that variables get passed on when the button is clicked.
Once the user clicks the button on the new html page, she should get redirected to the asp website to complete the rest of the purchase.

This is the code behind the aspx button on an ugly page

```
<input name="ctl00$Template$Purchase" value="Register" id="ctl00_Template_Purchase" title="Purchase" class="TextButton" type="submit">
```

FYI, I don't have access to the aspx code to change the look of that page, so this is workaround, to basically, link to the Purchase button with all the necessary variables.

I am very new to ASP. Thank you.

Comment: So, let me try to understand a little better. You have an aspx page you cannot change, and you want to create a new aspx page. When the user clicks the "Purchase" button on the new page, you want to redirect to the old page as if the user had clicked the old page's Purchase button? And the old page should be able to see any fields entered on the new page? If so, I think you'll need to modify the old page to make this work. Or am I way off?

Comment: The new webpage is a regular html page, not aspx. Is there no way to embed the product parameters of the old aspx page on the new html page? I can't change the old aspx page, but want to somehow link to that Purchase button, so that user can just get redirected to the Step 2 of the checkout process already with the product in the cart. Thank you

Comment: Unless the aspx page accepts query string parameters, I don't think it's possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: What does the query string look like? I can try and see if it works

Comment: I don't think this is possible... the nature of the aspx to send data to the server is stored within a `viewstate hidden field`. By default, aspx server side controls can have state because of this. When the page is posted, values from the controls are visible because of this hidden. On an HTML page, you do not have server controls or a `viewstate` that the server code can see.

Comment: I agree with David. The real problem is you want to use the code-behind of the old aspx page, and somehow invoke it from the new html page. That is, you most likely need to modify the old aspx page, or at least its server-side code-behind. If you can't modify the old aspx code, then you can't tell it it look for the fields/variables in a different place (such as the query string, or passed in from the new html page). Sorry!